# Adafruit Feather M0 Basic update bootloader

Tags: adafruit, bootloader, atmel-studio, samd21g

I bought a Feather M0 Basic from a reseller [Lawicel](https://www.lawicel-shop.se/) however I'm missing the 
UF2 boot feature. When I press the reset button two times I just
get a serial and have to program circuitpython using Bossa. The `UF2`
`FEATHERBOOT` usb storage drive as described  [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/welcome-to-circuitpython/installing-circuitpython) doesnt show up.

I have a ARM-ICE and wired up the Feather board via SWD. I 
can re-program the bootloader (first setting fuse to NVMCTRL_BOOTPROT 0x7
as described [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/proper-step-debugging-atsamd21-arduino-zero-m0/restoring-bootloader) ) via ARM-ICE.

However it seems that the Arduino bootloader [featherm0bootloader_160305.zip](https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/031/337/original/featherm0bootloader_160305.zip?1458155274) is an old one that doesnt support the UF2 usb storage device programming protocol.

Where can I download a more recent bootloader that supports UF2 ?

Comment: this? https://learn.adafruit.com/installing-circuitpython-on-samd21-boards/installing-the-uf2-bootloader

Comment: post a link of the actual product, not the homepage of the retailer

Comment: @Juraj : Thanks, that was the one I was looking for. Programmed it and now ```FEATHERBOOT``` is appearing.